# Media Type Splash Screen in iPhone iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, media, splash-screen

Wanna create a custom splash screen for the iPhone, but Im asking for opinion from all of you.

For what I understand, the splash screen is only a image (Default.png), so if I want to make the splash screen longer, the only way I can do is create a image then add the subview to the front? Then create a timer to call a method to remove the image from the view.

But then I want to create a media type splash screen, which will show audio, video and etc. So the question is what flow will it look like. The only way I think of is create a ViewController, then present it in a modal view. Later I also will add in an option to detect a tap from user, if tapped then the media will quit/hide/dismiss the fake splash screen and present the main view controller.

For now the flow of my thinking is like this:

*AppDelegate --> RootViewController --> SplashViewController(Modal View)*

is it possible to make it like this?

*AppDelegate --> SplashViewController --> RootViewController*

Is there any other way to show the media when the app start?

Any answer is appreciate, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the root view controller of your navigation controller to Be your splash screen.

Then just dont allow the user to navigate that low.

after the timer lapses, push onto the nav with animation:NO and your splash screen will be replaced.

Alternatively you can add your splash.. and when the timer lapses, you tell the splash screen to remove itself from its parent view, then add your root controller.

Comment: additionally, i would say make the default.png look just like the splash screen so when the app loads, the transition will be seamless.

Comment: so do you mean that the first start assign the self.window.rootViewController = splashViewController; then after the timer it assign to mainViewController?

The problem is if I want to add in a gestureRecognizer for touch to quit from the fake splash screen, where and how should I make it work. Create a delegate or using notification?

Comment: Im not 100% sure on the semantics.... I think you can just use [self.window addSubView:splash]; and then [splash removeFromSuperView]; [self.window addSubView:myRealRootView];